# Laravel: How to resolve and handle a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can see from `index.php` how get the `$response` object back four a `Http\Request`:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

Which is nearly what I want to do, but I need to swap the route and POST params for a new one. More specifically, I've got something like this:

```
class AjaxLoaderController extends Controller {

    public static function endpoint(\Illuminate\Http\Request $httpRequest) {

        $kernel = app()->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

        foreach($httpRequest->request->get('requests',[]) as $subReq) {
            $newReq = $httpRequest->duplicate(null,$subReq['data']);
            // how can I change the URL for $newReq to the resolved path for an arbitrary route name?

            $subRes = $kernel->handle($newReq);

            \Kymark\Dbg::log('$subReq',$subReq);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `$subReq` looks like:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "route" => "survey"
    "data" => array:1 [
      "companyId" => 3
    ]
  ]
]
```

So I want to resolve "survey" into a URL so that I can stuff it into `$newReq` and then hotswap the POST data in `$httpRequest` with "data", and then fire that off through the normal Laravel pipeline so that it calls a new controller action and gives me a new response.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing will put you in an infinite loop :(

because you are not changing the route.

If I want to do it I will create a new request then add the data to it

you should add \ before Illuminate...

```
$kernel = app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

...
and inside your loop:

```
//$newReq = $request->duplicate(null,$subReq);
$newReq = Request::create($subReq['route'], 'POST', $subReq['data']);

$subRes = $kernel->handle($newReq);
$subRes->send();
```

### finally you should not forget the csrf because you are sending a post request, you need to except your subReq routes from csrf or you have to send the token with the request,

you can except it from:

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

---

### or you can:

1. List item
2. duplicate the request. check this: [duplicate method](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_duplicate)
3. get the request server
4. change it for what you need
5. then initialize the new request with new parameters
6. then dispatch the route with new request :D

#### code:

```
        $subReq = [
            "route" => "survey",
            "data" => [
                "companyId" => 3,
                '_token' => csrf_token(), // if you dont want to except csrf
            ],
        ];


        $server = $request->server();

        $server['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'; // add it if you are initially sending a GET,
        $server['REQUEST_URI'] = $subReq['route'];

        $newRequest = $request->duplicate(null, $subReq['data'], null, null, null, $server);
        $newRequest->initialize([], $subReq['data'], [], $request->cookie(), [], $server, null);

        app()->instance('request', $newRequest);
        \Route::dispatch($newRequest);

         // or you can still do this
        // $kernel = app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
        // $subRes = $kernel->handle($newRequest);
        // $subRes->send();
```

#### now if you are initially sending a POST request you dont need to add the post method type to SERVER, but if not you have to add it, and you have to except the csrf, or add it to the attributes

### BTW you can still do at the end:

```
$kernel = app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$subRes = $kernel->handle($newRequest);
$subRes->send();
```

Comment: I was assuming `->duplicate` would duplicate the headers+cookies to satisfy the CSRF, no? Oh, but you're using `::create` now. I guess I'll have to pass that along too then, or bypass it like you said, since it's already been checked by the initial request.

Comment: you are right, I will update the answer, I have another Idea :D